# Is there a simple C or C++ library for transcoding FLAC to MP3?

Tags: c++, c, libraries, lame, flac

Right now, I'm taking the easy way out in my command line program by calling on the `flac`, `metaflac` and `lame` binaries, and of course, requiring that they are installed.

I would prefer to use a library to avoid this dependency. I find the documentation of libFLAC, LAME, and FFmpeg insufficient and programming them is not intuitive. Related questions here at StackOverflow receive terse answers referring to those libraries.

Are there any other options?

Comment: Letting the binaries do their job is The Unix Way At Its Finest. The easy way out is The Right Way Out.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [GStreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) library.  It may have what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Your choice is to require that the `flac` and `lame` programs are installed, or require that the libraries are installed.  Why is it easier to require libraries than to require command-line tools?

So, I strongly recommend that you just keep on doing what you are doing.  If you were writing a media player, it would make sense to use the libraries and decode the FLAC files yourself; but if you are just transcoding to MP3, the command-line tools are as good as any other solution, and simpler.  I think simplest is best.

"Are there just no options?"  I don't know what you mean by that; there are always options.  But without question, it will be more work to figure out how to call the libraries directly than to just call the command-line tools.  And if you already have a working solution involving the command-line tools, I suggest you just keep using it.

Comment: I could just include the libraries in the binary and distribute it that way.  It removes any dependencies.